# How to filter large data-sets by two attributes and split into subsets? R / Grep

Tags: r, split, subset

I found myself at the limits of the `grep()` function or perhaps there are efficient ways of doing this.

Start off a sample data-frame:

```
Date <- c( "31-DEC-2014","31-DEC-2014","31-DEC-2014","30-DEC-2014",
           "30-DEC-2014","30-DEC-2014", "29-DEC-2014","29-DEC-2014","29-DEC-2014" )

ISIN <- c("LU0168343191", "TW0002418001", "GB00B3FFY088","LU0168343191",
          "TW0002418001", "GB00B3FFY088","LU0168343191", "TW0002418001", "GB00B3FFY088")


price <-c(seq(1:9))

df <- as.data.frame(cbind(Date, ISIN, price))
```

And the desired Result is a `list()` containing subsets of the main data file which looks like the below (x3 for the 3 individual Identifiers in `Result_I`)

The idea is that the data should first filter by ISIN and **then** filter by Date. this 2 step process should keep my data intact.

```
Result_d <- c("31-DEC-2014", "30-DEC-2014","29-DEC-2014")
Result_I <- c("LU0168343191","LU0168343191","LU0168343191")
Result_P <- c(1,4,7)

Result_df <- cbind(Result_d, Result_I, Result_P)
```

Please keep in mid the above is for demo purposes and the real data-set has 5M rows and 50 columns over a period of 450+ different dates as per `Result_d` so i am lookign for something that is applicable irrespective of nrow or ncol

**What i have so far:**

I take all unique dates and store:

```
Unique_Dates <- unique(df$Date)
```

The same for the Identifiers:

```
Unique_ID <- unique(df$ISIN)
```

Now the grepping issue:

If i wanted all rows containing `Unique_Dates` i would do something like:

```
pattern <- paste(Unique_dates, collapse = "|")

result <- as.matrix(df[grep(pattern, df$Date),])
```

and this will retrieve basically the entire data set. i am wondering if anyone knows an efficient way of doing this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `df %>%
  dplyr::filter(grepl(pattern = "LU", ISIN))` and for dates and ranges use `lubridate`

Comment: It seems like you want to keep only the first row for each date, so: `df[!duplicated(df$Date),]` perhaps?

Comment: your code outputs an error. it is also limited to "LU" where i have roughly 8000 unique ID's here. I also have multiple entries of the same ID on the same Date so it's important that the unique Date filter is applied

Comment: Maximus, in order to preserve the data quality it's important they are filtered 1 first by ID then by Date

Comment: Alex, try to better describe how your output is computed.

Comment: As @PM suggested this may work `df %>%
  dplyr::group_by(Date) %>%
  slice(1)`

Comment: @AlexBădoi then it would be: `dfn <- df[grep('LU', df$ISIN),]; dfn[!duplicated(dfn$Date),]`

Comment: or: `dfn <- df[df$ISIN == 'LU0168343191',]; dfn[!duplicated(dfn$Date),]`

Comment: thanks for taking time to help out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df)`), grouped by 'Date', specify the 'i' based on the index returned with `grep` and Subset the Data.table (`.SD`) based on the 'i' index.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[grep("LU", ISIN), .SD, by = Date]
#           Date         ISIN price
#1: 31-DEC-2014 LU0168343191     1
#2: 30-DEC-2014 LU0168343191     4
#3: 29-DEC-2014 LU0168343191     7
```

Comment: applying to my main data i get this error: Error in `[.data.table`(setDT(PORTFO_Dat2), grep("LU0168343191", PORTFO_Dat2$ISIN.code),  : 
  The items in the 'by' or 'keyby' list are length (5114748). Each must be same length as rows in x or number of rows returned by i (120).

Comment: @AlexBădoi  I didn't use `PORTFO_Dat2$`.  It should be `ISIN.code`

Comment: it's amazing how well this worked and how simple to apply. All i have to do is loop across all my ID's. Thank you

Comment: hi arkun, could you please explain what the .SD part of the function does?

Comment: @AlexBădoi  I updated the post.  `.SD` means Subset of Data.table

Answer (score 2):

Using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

Date <- c( "31-Dec-2014","31-Dec-2014","31-Dec-2014","30-Dec-2014",
           "30-Dec-2014","30-Dec-2014", "29-Dec-2014","29-Dec-2014","29-Dec-2014" )

ISIN <- c("LU0168343191", "TW0002418001", "GB00B3FFY088","LU0168343191",
          "TW0002418001", "GB00B3FFY088","LU0168343191", "TW0002418001", "GB00B3FFY088")


price <-c(seq(1:9))

DF <- data.frame(Date, ISIN, price,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
DF$Date=as.Date(DF$Date,"%d-%b-%Y")



#Examine data ranges and frequencies

#date range
range(DF$Date)

#date frequency count
table(DF$Date)

#ISIN frequency count
table(DF$ISIN)


#select ISINs for filtering, with user defined choice of filters

# numISIN = 2
# subISIN = head(names(sort(table(DF$ISIN))),numISIN)


subISIN = names(sort(table(DF$ISIN)))[2]


subDF=DF %>%
dplyr::group_by(ISIN) %>%
dplyr::arrange(ISIN,Date) %>%
dplyr::filter(ISIN %in% subISIN) %>%  
as.data.frame()

#> subDF
#        Date         ISIN price
#1 2014-12-29 LU0168343191     7
#2 2014-12-30 LU0168343191     4
#3 2014-12-31 LU0168343191     1
```